# How can I attach a DataContext to this ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contextmenu, observablecollection, datacontext

I have an ObservableCollection that I'm trying to use with a ContextMenu MenuItem:

```
private void MenuItem_TapCopyDetails(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    //entries is a table in my datamodel
    var currentItem = ((sender as MenuItem).DataContext) as entries; //when it doesn't work, this is null
    if (currentItem.name == null) //and this throws a null reference exception
        MessageBox.Show("null");
    else
        MessageBox.Show(currentItem.name.ToString());
}
```

But the first line is null. I use that methodology several times, but here it fails. Actually as you can see in the XAML there's another call to this method and it works fine.

The only difference is in the XAML; I use binding on the TextBlocks slightly differently:

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <controls:Pivot Name="pivotControl" Margin="0,-20,0,0" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <controls:PivotItem Header="search" >
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox Height="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                         Name="listBoxHome" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchPeopleResults}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Tap="StackPanel_Tap" Margin="5,0,0,0">

                                <!--These MenuItems work properly-->
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="copy details" Tap="MenuItem_TapCopyDetails" />
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="bookmark person" Tap="MenuItem_Tap_BookmarkPerson" />
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="22" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dob}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <controls:PivotItem Header="detail">
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="stackDetail">

                    <!--This MenuItem returns a null exception-->
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="copy details" Tap="MenuItem_TapCopyDetails" />
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EntryDetails[0].name}" FontSize="48" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EntryDetails[0].dob}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EntryDetails[0].info}" FontSize="26.667" />

                <ListBox Height="317" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                         Name="listBoxExamples" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NotableQuotes}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Examples sentences" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0">

                                <!--These MenuItems work properly-->
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="copy quote" Tap="MenuItem_TapCopyQuote" />
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="bookmark quote" Tap="MenuItem_Tap_BookmarkQuote" />
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding quote}" FontSize="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,15,0,0" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

How can I assign `entries` or my ObservableCollection as the DataContext to the ContextMenu?

Edit:

```
//View Model
namespace AppDatabase.ViewModel
{
    public class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //LINQ to SQL datacontext for the database.
        private TheDataContext appDB;

        public AppViewModel(string dbConnectionString)
        {
            appDB = new TheDataContext(dbConnectionString);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<entries> _searchPeopleResults;
        public ObservableCollection<entries> SearchPeopleResults
        {
            get { return _searchPeopleResults; }
            set { _searchPeopleResults = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<entries> _entryDetals;
        public ObservableCollection<entries> EntryDetails
        {
            get { return _entryDetals; }
            set { _entryDetals = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<quotes> _notableQuotes;
        public ObservableCollection<quotes> NotableQuotes
        {
            get { return _notableQuotes; }
            set { _notableQuotes = value; }
        }

        //...

        //Query the database and load collections used by the pivot pages
        public void LoadEntryDetails(int entryID)
        {
            var details = from entries entry in appDB.Entries
                          where entry.id.Equals(entryID)
                          select entry;

            _entryDetals = new ObservableCollection<entries>(details);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EntryDetails");
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without knowing a bit about the model that backs your XAML. What is bound to your UI?

Comment: @ColinE I've added the view model, I'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the third line with the original. This one works.

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="detail">
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="stackDetail" DataContext="{Binding Path=EntryDetails[0]}">
```